# How to run ssh -vvv host through a python script?

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I would like to check the authentication method (whether public key or password or both) of a bunch of IP addresses through SSH -vvv host command using a python script that does not require password.

basically I am interested in the below line of the result:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Here is what I have tried but it does not work since it asks for password.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("ssh -vvv host", shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output,stderr = process.communicate()
status = process.poll()
print output
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

```
ssh -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -vvv
```

That instructs the client not to try keyboard interactive or password authentication, but the server will still send which methods it supports. It may still ask for confirmation if the host is unknown (could be disabled with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`). Maybe you'll also want to disable other authentication methods [listed in the manual](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config).

edit: `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=none` should also work

Comment: Thanks. this works for returning only one line but then my python script is still running. Do you know a way to stop it after this line is returned?

Comment: After the communicate call the ssh process should have exited, or does the communicate call not return? In any case, you should probably also set `stdin=PIPE` so it will be closed in the communicate call.

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
try:
    client.connect('ssh.example.com')
except AuthenticationException as e:
    print ('got exception {}'.format(e.__dict__))
except :
    print ('got exception: NOT AUTH !!!')
```

now just loop it as many times. no need for subprocess etc paramiko is great.......

Comment: Thanks. but I specifically want SSH -vvv